# How to periodically change background-image site-wide?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I am trying to set up an random alternating background that changes periodically across the whole site. E.g. at any given point the random background image would be the same on every page for a period of time.

Currently I have background images that change every 30 mins with this javascript: (from here: http://www.blogfodder.co.uk/post/2008/01/JavaScript-CSS-Random-Background-Image.aspx)

The problem however is that each link randomizes the background on each new page.

```
function ChangeCSSBgImg() {
    if (!document.getElementById) return false;

    var MyElement = "bgimg" 
    var ImgPath = "../i/" 

    if (!document.getElementById(MyElement)) return false;

    var random_images = new Array ();
    random_images[0] = "bg1.jpg"; // these are the background images
    random_images[1] = "bg2.jpg"; 
    random_images[2] = "bg3.jpg"; 
    random_images[3] = "bg4.jpg"; 
    random_images[4] = "bg5.jpg"; 

    var $header = document.getElementById(MyElement);
    var $backgroundurl = $header.style.backgroundImage;
    var ImgURL = "url(" + ImgPath + random_images[rand(random_images.length)] + ")";

    if ($backgroundurl != ImgURL) {
        $header.style.backgroundImage = ImgURL; 
    }

    movement = setTimeout("ChangeCSSBgImg()",108000000); 
}


/* random number generator */
function rand(n) {
    return ( Math.floor ( Math.random ( ) * n ) );
}

/* Custom onload function */
function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            oldonload();
            func();
        }
    }
}
/* trigger onload */
addLoadEvent(ChangeCSSBgImg);
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you hash the current time to pick an image? e.g. a simplistic one would be, have six images, then pick the image based on the 2nd-to-last digit in the current time, e.g.

- 10:08 - pick image #0
- 10:15 - pick image #1
- 10:20 - pick image #2
- 10:51 - pick image #5

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you don't store any info for this - it should work from *a priori* info, such as the system time as suggested by Jeffrey Kemp. This will make it much more stable and work across more user agents.

Getting a unix time stamp for instance, will allow you to change the background on a per second basis.

Remember that some users have slower connections, and may not load the background image immediately.

A simple way would be to use a setInterval that iterates through an array of images every 30 minutes, and resets after the last image is chosen.

Answer (score 1):

> Jeffrey's idea seems like a good and simple solution for this purpose unless the backgrounds needs to be totally random and identical among all visitors (which would require a server side solution):

Use javascript to set the proper class based on time (hour, minute or whatever).
Then set the image with CSS: `.background-0 { background-image: ... }`

Example:

- `<div class="background-0"></div>` *(minutes 00-09)*
- `<div class="background-1"></div>` *(minutes 10-19)*
- `<div class="background-2"></div>` *(minutes 20-29)*
- `<div class="background-3"></div>` *(minutes 30-39)*
- `<div class="background-4"></div>` *(minutes 40-49)*
- `<div class="background-5"></div>` *(minutes 50-59)*

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is either have programmatically generated CSS on the web server (i.e. a script with CSS output) or dynamically change the stylesheet link when generating the web pages.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the background image info in the user's session and update it server-side periodically.  This is assuming you're using a language that is parsed on the server though.

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript, you can do something like this.

```
function changeBg()
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(bg/'+ new Date().getHours() +'.gif)';
}
    window.setInterval(changeBg, 1000);
```

Wrap this in a Javascript file and link it to every page of your site.

This script will change the background of the website, based on the hour of time (ie 0-23 hours)

Here, the images are stored in the `bg` directory with names ranging from `0` to `23`. There is no randomness involved, since the images will be selected based on the hour of the day. You can slightly change the script for your need.

Answer (score -1):

```
< script type = "text/javascript" > var now = new Date () ;
var hours = now. getHours() ;
//Keep in code - Written by Computerhope.com
//Place this script in your HTML heading section
document. write( 'It' s now: ', hours, ' < br >< br > ');
document.bgColor="#CC9900";
//18-19 night

if (hours > 17 && hours < 20){
    document.write (' < body style = "background-color: orange" > ');
}
//20-21 night
else if (hours > 19 && hours < 22){
    document.write (' < body style = "background-color: orangered" > ');
}
//22-4 night
else if (hours > 21 || hours < 5){
    document.write (' < body style = "background-color: #C0C0C0;" > ');
}
//9-17 day
else if (hours > 8 && hours < 18){
    document.write (' < body style = "background-color: #616D7E" > ');
}
//7-8 day
else if (hours > 6 && hours < 9){
    document.write (' < body style = "background-color: skyblue" > ');
}
//5-6 day
else if (hours > 4 && hours < 7){
    document.write (' < body style = "background-color: steelblue" > ');
}
else {
    document.write (' < body style = "background-color: white" > ');
}
</script>
```